# Export OpenSSL public key to file

Tags: php, openssl, php-openssl

How can I export only the public key to a file(.pem) with PHP?
Of course it is possible to export the whole certificate and a private key but I can't find a solution to export a public key.

The file should look like

```
-----BEGIN PUBLIC KEY-----
MIIBIjANBgkqhkiG9w0BAQEFAAOCAQ8AMIIBCgKCAQEArDjwWcPjZRQpiMRsG1fG
kudSYEHnSR57dKUoK+qIc++YZSCWG/q460LrNtQ/EBx6ZdJJnhBk4EwY0snb7TEr
pH5efU2BuCygO3f78DozMxNvvHFFfZ1uw4hobBMSKLKtVcJKmh7r7dvgXtKWdqJf
sUmr2V3LDXTF3r6G5NEorGC4crcSByAvyPatUKRR5t6kAuU8pnWrHnDo+GoSjHy2
vvaUuds6FxHMieFXKrnN8dk6VPpV2PEwzSAk9Ofbq3oZxkIhVGTHjgFPF9tIx3Vu
yo+S4KCP6sxmEt1/p4B5VsCsRU4STbA5jC8qK9vJ1YhMD6tK5FWreaDiWL3wBjf5
xwIDAQAB
-----END PUBLIC KEY-----
```

Comment: Check this http://php.net/manual/en/function.openssl-pkey-get-public.php

Comment: I already tried - but this gives me only the public key if I import a file with public key (or cert and / or private key).
But how can I export the public key into this file after creating it (with openssl_pkey_new(), openssl_pkey_get_details()["key"]?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Can PHP OpenSSL generate private/public key/certificate pairs?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7414044/can-php-openssl-generate-private-public-key-certificate-pairs)

Comment: Not really - the questions was not how to create but how to export the key(s) to file(s).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

That's the solution. Thanks to https://www.virendrachandak.com/techtalk/encryption-using-php-openssl/

```
// Generate the public key for the private key
$key = openssl_pkey_get_details($privateKey); // $privateKey is created with openssl_pkey_new()

// Save the public key in public.pem file
file_put_contents('public.pem', $key['key']);
```