# Generate private key RSA with PKCS1

Tags: php, openssl

Is there a way to generate private key via OpenSSL in PHP using [openssl-pkey-new](http://php.net/manual/en/function.openssl-pkey-new.php) in RSA and PKCS1?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Can PHP OpenSSL generate private/public key/certificate pairs?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7414044/can-php-openssl-generate-private-public-key-certificate-pairs)

Comment: No dup - I need generate RSA in  PKCS1 format.

Comment: [PKCS1 is not secure](http://stackoverflow.com/a/34088308/2224584).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

if you mean private key with BEGIN RSA PRIVATE KEY header then there is one issue in PHP that does not have simple solution. Basically PHP compiled with OpenSSL 1.0+ produce PKCS#8 PEM formatted private keys and it seems like there is no way how to generate it in PKCS#1 format anymore (at least I was not able to find solution).

https://bugs.php.net/bug.php?id=53850

[Why different private key strings under Linux or Windows?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9678202/why-different-private-key-strings-under-linux-or-windows)

There is also library called [phpseclib](https://github.com/phpseclib/phpseclib) that shoul be able to do it. (but I don't have personal experience with it).

http://phpseclib.sourceforge.net/rsa/examples.html#create,pkcs1,pkcs1pub,sign1,enc1,