# PKCS12 file and Private key - PHP

Tags: php, ssl, x509, phpseclib

I'm creating a an X509 certificate using phpseclib and all of that seems to be fine. Once I've created the certificate, I save it down as a pkcs12 file in PHP using the private key associated with my certificate. However, once I read that file, the private key I get back is different. Shouldn't the key be the same?

For instance, let's say I call:

```
openssl_pkcs12_export_to_file($cert , $write_loc, $priv_key , $pass);
```

Works great, now when I read the file with:

```
openssl_pkcs12_read($write_loc, $certs, $pass);
```

The output in $certs['pkey'] differs from the $priv_key I passed to the export_to_file method above.

Surely they must be the same, or am I mixing up 2 completely different things?

Thank you!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think what's going is explained at [PHP RSA key creation](https://stackoverflow.com/q/31922094/569976)

Basically, you're using a key that starts off with `-----BEGIN RSA PRIVATE KEY-----` and the key you're getting back starts off with `-----BEGIN PRIVATE KEY-----`.

The former is a PKCS1 formatted private key and the latter is a PKCS8 formatted private key. The latter has the private key type embedded within the base64-encoded data itself whereas the former has the private key type embedded in the human readable string.

Some versions of PHP / OpenSSL output the PKCS8 key and others output the PKCS1 key..

Comment: Hi there, yes you're right. I figured this out yesterday after seeing http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20065304/what-is-the-differences-between-begin-rsa-private-key-and-begin-private-key and scrapped key generation with phpseclib and went to PHP's openssl functions. Even if I tell phpseclib to use PKCS8, it doesn't. I imagine that is a bug to raise with them.

Comment: It works if you're using the newest version. If you don't think it does I'll make a bet with you. $10.00 via PayPal says that it works and that you're either using it incorrectly or are using an out-of-date version.

Comment: So if you're right and it's a bug with the latest version (1.0.0) I'll pay you $10.00 and if you're wrong you'll pay me $10.00.

Comment: If you need $10, i can send it you anyway. I don't know what version I was using, and I won't be able to find out until next week anyway. In any case, as it stands, I had to get openssl to work with PHP because I needed to use PKCS12 which is not supported by the library. version aside, though, I was using the setPrivateKeyFormat() method and passing it the PKCS8 constant, so version is the most likely explanation.

Comment: I don't need $10 lol. I was just trying to incentivize you to help me out. I'm not the lead dev of phpseclib but I did a pull request for the PKCS8 feature so I'm a bit motivated to see that it works for people lol. But I agree about PKCS12. That's a little more involved than PKCS8.

Comment: I'm back at work on Tuesday so will have a look then and let you know.

Comment: I just checked my composer.json file. I think version was probably the problem (now I'm using PHP's openssl methods anyway) as that has 0.3.10. Wonder where I got that from!